# Creating an untouchable file for users

Tags: permissions

So I am trying to create a file which cannot be "touched", for example this could be the file "/etc/random". If I set this files permissions to "1000000000", would a random user be able to cp this file to their home directory?

My understanding would suggest that it would not be possible as there are no RWX permissions for any of the users/groups. So even if say the setUID bit was set on CP, it still would be inaccessible?

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have any permissions for the file then the user can't copy it to `home` or anywhere else. If the user has execute permissions on the directory then the user can traverse into the directory and `ls -l` the file but it still won't be possible to copy it.

If you want to have the most protection, then as `root`, you can navigate to `opt`, for example, and then create another directory beneath it, remove the execute permission for `others` from that directory, and then create or place the file inside. That way, the user wouldn't even be able to enter the directory or even see any details about the file. The only catch is that if they found out the name of it, they could see that it exists but they wouldn't be able to copy it or read its contents which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone can read a file they cannot copy it.

Be aware though, that with write permission to the parent directory someone can move the file to another place on the same filesystem, or even delete it.